# hiddenSegments images directory stops them from displaying on website

Tags: asp.net, iis, hidden

Fighting with this for a few hours now.. This HP Web Inspect is complaining about my images folder throwing a 403 when it should be a 404. so I use hiddenSegments to hide it but then the images don't display. Help! :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i experienced, When deploying a project in website much better to move out all images and put it in a project folder itself. do not use any image folder.

You have some option:

```
1.  <img src="images/img.png" />
2.  <img src="~img.png" />
3.  <img src="img.png" />
4.  <img src="~images/img.png" />
```

My work is using with number 1 and dont have any problem in IIS.
but the option is if not working then this is the time that you have to move it out from its folder.

Good luck!

Comment: Till me if it is woked or not.

Comment: i think i was overlooking the fact that each image has gets separately requested through the web browser no matter what.. Thus it has to be http accessible.. i think the ~ needs to go before the / .. i tried these ./ etc .. but it's all irrelevant given a GET is made for each image... thanks alot for the response ! :)